# Heatmap appears offset after call to setCenter in OpenLayers

Tags: javascript, openlayers, heatmap

I have a heatmap and set of markers that are rendering fine in OpenLayers. Afterwards, when I change the center of the map programmatically using map.setCenter the heatmap appears offset by exactly double the change of center location. (So if the new center is 1km east, the heatmap appears offset by 2km east)

It's almost as though the redrawing of the heatmap layer is over compensating.

Has anyone come across this before and solved it? I've tried called heatmapLayer.redraw() to no avail.

I'm using OpenLayers 2.13.1 and Patrick Weid's heatmap.js' openlayers support.

Comment: Please provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) (working and syntactically correct code) so we can reproduce your problem.

Comment: I would love to, but the code sample is tightly integrated with a database, with a wrapper API around the widget. Given this is a common scenario I was hoping someone had encountered it without needing a code sample. I wouldn't have though calling setCenter() would mean it's a code bug when it's working fine otherwise.

Comment: Can you at least provide a screenshot or some more context? As it is, it's really tough to understand what the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to find a fix. No idea why this seems to work though when heatmaplayer.redraw() doesn't.

For the benefit of others:-

```
this.map.setCenter( new OpenLayers.LonLat(lon,lat).transform(
  this.transformWgs84, this.map.projection), zoom,true,true);
```

the second 'true' did the trick. According to the OpenLayers docs this should just force a zoom change. It seems to also force a heatmap layer redraw. (The first true parameter forces drag events)

Docs: http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Map-js.html#OpenLayers.Map.setCenter